# I get 3 btns to set the property.But failed with "exc_bad_access" when clicked.I run it on iOS5 using ARC, can anyone help me?

Tags: objective-c

I get 3 btns to set the property.But failed with "exc_bad_access" when clicked.I run it on iOS5 using ARC. I use alloc+init pattern, but still failed. I don't know why.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *testVariableValues;

@synthesize testVariableValues = _testVariableValues;

- (NSDictionary *)testVariableValues
{
    if (!_testVariableValues) {
        _testVariableValues = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"0", @"x",@"0", @"a",@"0", @"b", nil]];
    }
    return _testVariableValues;
}

- (IBAction)testPressed:(UIButton *)sender 
{
    if ([@"Test 1" isEqualToString:sender.currentTitle]) {
        self.testVariableValues = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1", @"x", @"2", @"a", "3", "b", nil];
    } else if([@"Test 2" isEqualToString:sender.currentTitle]) {
        self.testVariableValues = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"-4", @"x", @"3", @"a", "4", "b", nil];
    } else if([@"Test 3" isEqualToString:sender.currentTitle]) {
        self.testVariableValues = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a stack trace with this? If not, can you enable breakpoints on exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

Your `NSDictionary` is autoreleased.
Try apply a retain or an alloc+init pattern.

```
self.testVariableValues = 
  [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1", [...], "b", nil]
    retain];
```

or

```
if (!_testVariableValues) {
    _testVariableValues = [NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"0", @"x",@"0", @"a",@"0", @"b", nil];
}
```

Comment: Your reply would solve if the poster is not using ARC. But my assumption is that he is, and in that case, you cannot call retain explicitly. It requires clarification on the poster's end though.

Comment: Sorry to tell that I use ARC, i tried with alloc+init, but it still falied with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.